# MySQL table insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know if I am doing a correct table write, it seems to be failing.

```
while($n != 1)
  {
   $randstring = "live_".RandomString();
   echo "<br>".$username."<br>";
   echo $randstring."<br>";
   $idcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM streamer_ids WHERE streamer_id='".$randstring."'"); //check for matching random strings
   if (!(mysql_num_rows($idcheck)>0))
   {
    $n=1; //It has found a random string that does not match.
   }
  }
//if it has reached this far, it has a unique id. Now that id is being written to the database.
  $temp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium) VALUES(".$username.",".$randstring.","0")");
  $temp->closeCursor();
```

Be aware that last part is badly butchered, and is what I need help with.

Comment: 1. Can you post the error you are getting 2. Mandatory SQL Injection warning - use parameters 3. Your uniqueness check for matching random strings seems redundant - what are u trying to achieve with it?

Comment: It needs to be completely unique, it will continue regenerating random strings if there is a match.

Comment: this logic is likely to fail in a multi-user scenario unless you have a constraint on the DB column - in which case - i would consider this checking here redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing string delimiters in your insert statement.

I.e.

`$temp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium) VALUES('".$username."','".$randstring."','0')");`

Also, I don't know where the $username value is coming from, but you should probably sanitize it in order to prevent SQL injections. I.e. Running `addslashes` on it.

- Christian

Comment: I decided to just use:   
$temp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium) VALUES($username,$randstring,0')");
  $temp->closeCursor();

Answer (score 0):

you can put your insert logic into if row_count > 0  clauses, also you are getting errors because you generate query using string concatenation, not parameters. Use parameters and it will work=) Your current code is simply dangerous.

Also your select * statement can be replaced by select count(*) which will make your logic more clear cause you will be requesting only required data from db, in this case, whether there are rows or not.