# MySQL table insertion

Tags: php, mysql

Is this accepted syntax? More importantly, will it work?

```
$temp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium) VALUES($username,$randstring,0)");
    $temp->closeCursor();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL table insertion ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394723/mysql-table-insertion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to put quotes around the strings to make it work.**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium)
             VALUES('$username', '$randstring', '0')");
```

Sp. if you are connected to MySQL, then it will work WITH these changes. Also, don't forget to take preventive measures against SQL injection attacks. For that, you should do this to all the variables before running the query:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$randstring = mysql_real_escape_string($randstring);
$premium = intval($premium); //supposing it is always integer.
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the second time you've helped me out :)

Comment: Also, be aware of magic quotes, in particular magic_quotes_gpc, enabled by default in PHP prior to 5.3.0: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempquery = "INSERT INTO streamer_ids (username,streamer_id,premium) VALUES($username,$randstring,0);
$result = mysql_query($tempquery);
```

Thanks.